# Formatting output on CURDATE() and NOW() create wrong digits/letters

Tags: mysql, node.js, webstorm

I am working in Webstorm, with NodeJS and MySQL. 
When I run my "node app.js" file in the cmd with CURDATE and NOW, the letter "t" is used instead of a space, and instead of being a digit the last thing is the letter "Z". Looks like this:
   date: 2017-07-19T04:00:00.000Z,
   now: 2017-07-19T19:23:29.000Z }

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple replacement in Date Object

```js
var now = new Date().toISOString();
console.log( now );
var nowClean = now.replace('T',' ');
console.log(nowClean);
```